# Homebrew command to update PHP : Error: No available formula for php56

Tags: homebrew

I am trying to update PHP on my Mac OS X machine using Homebrew, and I am receiving the following output:

```
*********:Library *********$ brew install php56
Error: No available formula for php56 
==> Searching formulae...
==> Searching taps...
homebrew/php/php56-amqp         homebrew/php/php56-phalcon
homebrew/php/php56-apcu         homebrew/php/php56-pimple
homebrew/php/php56-augmentedtypes   homebrew/php/php56-proctitle
homebrew/php/php56-binpack      homebrew/php/php56-propro
homebrew/php/php56-blitz        homebrew/php/php56-protobuf
homebrew/php/php56-boxwood      homebrew/php/php56-pspell
homebrew/php/php56-chdb         homebrew/php/php56-pthreads
homebrew/php/php56-couchbase        homebrew/php/php56-qr
homebrew/php/php56-crypto       homebrew/php/php56-raphf
homebrew/php/php56-dbase        homebrew/php/php56-redis
homebrew/php/php56-dbus         homebrew/php/php56-redland
homebrew/php/php56-dmtx         homebrew/php/php56-riak
homebrew/php/php56-eio          homebrew/php/php56-runkit
homebrew/php/php56-ev           homebrew/php/php56-scrypt
homebrew/php/php56-event        homebrew/php/php56-snappy
homebrew/php/php56-fast_assert      homebrew/php/php56-snmp
homebrew/php/php56-gearman      homebrew/php/php56-sodium
homebrew/php/php56-geoip        homebrew/php/php56-solr
homebrew/php/php56-gmagick      homebrew/php/php56-sphinx
homebrew/php/php56-gmp          homebrew/php/php56-spl-types
homebrew/php/php56-graphdat     homebrew/php/php56-ssh2
homebrew/php/php56-grpc         homebrew/php/php56-stats
homebrew/php/php56-hprose       homebrew/php/php56-stemmer
homebrew/php/php56-htscanner        homebrew/php/php56-suhosin
homebrew/php/php56-http         homebrew/php/php56-sundown
homebrew/php/php56-igbinary     homebrew/php/php56-svm
homebrew/php/php56-imagick      homebrew/php/php56-swoole
homebrew/php/php56-inclued      homebrew/php/php56-symfony-debug
homebrew/php/php56-intl         homebrew/php/php56-thrift
homebrew/php/php56-ioncubeloader    homebrew/php/php56-tidy
homebrew/php/php56-jsmin        homebrew/php/php56-timezonedb
homebrew/php/php56-judy         homebrew/php/php56-tokyotyrant
homebrew/php/php56-leveldb      homebrew/php/php56-twig
homebrew/php/php56-libevent     homebrew/php/php56-uopz
homebrew/php/php56-libsodium        homebrew/php/php56-uploadprogress
homebrew/php/php56-libvirt      homebrew/php/php56-uuid
homebrew/php/php56-lz4          homebrew/php/php56-varnish
homebrew/php/php56-lzf          homebrew/php/php56-vld
homebrew/php/php56-magickwand       homebrew/php/php56-wbxml
homebrew/php/php56-mailparse        homebrew/php/php56-xcache
homebrew/php/php56-mcrypt       homebrew/php/php56-xdebug
homebrew/php/php56-mecab        homebrew/php/php56-xhgui
homebrew/php/php56-memcache     homebrew/php/php56-xhp
homebrew/php/php56-memcached        homebrew/php/php56-xhprof
homebrew/php/php56-midgard2     homebrew/php/php56-xmldiff
homebrew/php/php56-mongo        homebrew/php/php56-xxtea
homebrew/php/php56-mosquitto        homebrew/php/php56-yac
homebrew/php/php56-msgpack      homebrew/php/php56-yaf
homebrew/php/php56-mustache     homebrew/php/php56-yaml
homebrew/php/php56-mysqlnd_ms       homebrew/php/php56-yar
homebrew/php/php56-oauth        homebrew/php/php56-yaz
homebrew/php/php56-opcache      homebrew/php/php56-yp
homebrew/php/php56-parsekit     homebrew/php/php56-yrmcds
homebrew/php/php56-pcntl        homebrew/php/php56-zmq
homebrew/php/php56-pdflib       homebrew/php/php56-zookeeper
homebrew/php/php56-pdo-dblib        homebrew/php/php56
homebrew/php/php56-pdo-pgsql
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

First add the tap by running:

```
brew tap homebrew/homebrew-php
```

Comment: Worked for me on OSX High Sierra. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like this was deprecated... `$ brew tap homebrew/homebrew-php
Error: homebrew/php was deprecated. This tap is now empty as all its formulae were migrated.`  This tap was archived on 31st March 2018. See https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php

Comment: So now this is in core how does one install it :S

Comment: Now getting error:  `Error: homebrew/php was deprecated. This tap is now empty as all its formulae were migrated.`